# How to save visited pages by jquery cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

I want save the visited pages in jquery cookies as a array. What will be useful jquery cookie  or session, but if is use session it again restores the session if I open the firefox, how can I do this with jquery cookie.How can I achieve this?

Comment: I doubt you will be able to do that as cookie has limited lenght

Comment: Also, keep in mind there's no such thing as a "jquery cookie".  Cookies are a feature of the browser and they can be accessed via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Since the array can vary in length, it's not reasonable to store it in a cookie.

You should instead use cookies to associate user IDs with users, and then use a static, persistent map to match IDs with this array of visited pages.